# Check if value exists in array before inserting into database

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have an array that is returned from an API although some keys/values are not present all of the time.

example array

```
Array
(
    [example0] => data
    [example1] => data
    [example2] => data
    [example3] => data
)
```

Now if I use a query such as below

```
$dbh = $this->database->prepare("INSERT INTO table(example0, example1, example2, example3)VALUES(:example0, :example1, :example2, :example3)");
    $dbh->execute(array(
        "example0" => $data['example0'],
        "example1" => $data['example1'],
        "example2" => $data['example2'],
        "example3" => $data['example3']
    ));
```

It will work fine. But when the API returns an array like

```
Array
(
    [example0] => data
    [example1] => data
    [example3] => data
)
```

It will cause an error due to a value not being set, is there a way to just have it enter nothing into the column rather than throw an error? I am using a really big query for this so writing an if/else for each value would not be a good idea (in my opinion, for performance wise)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the key is set and eventually is there is a value:

```
if(isset($array['your_key']) && !empty($array['your_key'])) { }
```

I cannot make it clear from your code but validate everything before you use it in a query.

[Edit] Example:

```
$keys = array('example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4');
$use_in_query = array();

foreach($keys as $key)
{
    if(isset($array[$key]) && !empty($array[$key])) $use_in_query[$key] = $array[$key];
}

Now you can use the $use_in_query var in your query.

$dbh->execute($use_in_query);
```

[/Edit]

Comment: I see, so rather than write out every if isset just put it inside a foreach loop?

Comment: Exactly. Maybe you even have already a definition of the fields and you can use those instead of redefining them.